# How to use a Function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm Trying to make a function in jQuery

```
function Formulier1() {
     var usr_length = $(this).val().length;

     if(usr_length == 0){
          error.push("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
     }
}
```

but when im calling the function

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
     Formulier1();
});
```

They dont can't see the further code

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
     alert("Doesnt comes here");
     $("#error").html('');
     if(error == ""){
          //do something
     }else{
          $('#error').append(error);

          error = [""];
     }
});
```

I forgot something to do? or im doing something wrong?
when I put the code without an extra function but put it into the `gebruikersnaam focusout` it works fine.

I want to use the code `Formulier1` more then once thats why I wanted into an extra function!

Comment: Use like this $("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(Formulier1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$(this)` as a paremeter in your `Formulier` function.

For example:

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
    Formulier1($(this)); 
});

function Formulier1($this) {
    var usr_length = $this.val().length;

    if(usr_length == 0){
        error.push("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah thanx, I forget i used this, mostely i hated it to use it because of this ^^

Comment: @Erwin You should handle it as in Bala answer

Answer (score 2):

You just bind function name  in callback

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(Formulier1);
```

OR use **[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** function if you have to pass more arguments

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
     Formulier1.call(this);
});
```

Comment: ↑↑↑ And so `this` is refering  to `#gebruikersnaam` element

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object to that function

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
            Formulier1(this);
});
```

then your function will be

```
function Formulier1(obj) {
     var usr_length = $(obj).val().length;

     if(usr_length == 0){
          error.push("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
     }
}
```